# Vue component doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need some Vue.js for a project but when I go to the page with the Vue component the part doesn't show up. I'm new with Vue.js so I don't really know what to do in this situation. I've tried to search but nothing really helped me.

Here is the code.

My Blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Chats</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <chat-messages :messages="messages"></chat-messages>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <chat-form
                        v-on:messagesent="addMessage"
                        :user="{{ Auth::user() }}"
                    ></chat-form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

my `app.js`:

```
import FollowButton from './components/FollowButton.vue';
app.component('follow-button', FollowButton);

app.mount('#app');

require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('chat-messages', require('./components/ChatMessages.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-form', require('./components/ChatForm.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        messages: []
    },

    created() {
        this.fetchMessages()
     
Echo.private('chat')
.listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
  this.messages.push({
    message: e.message.message,
    user: e.user
  });
});
;
    },
    

    methods: {
        fetchMessages() {
            axios.get('/messages').then(response => {
                this.messages = response.data;
            });
        },

        addMessage(message) {
            this.messages.push(message);

            axios.post('/messages', message).then(response => {
              console.log(response.data);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And finally my 2 components:

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="btn-input" type="text" name="message" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." v-model="newMessage" @keyup.enter="sendMessage">

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat" @click="sendMessage">
                Send
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['user'],

        data() {
            return {
                newMessage: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            sendMessage() {
                this.$emit('messagesent', {
                    user: this.user,
                    message: this.newMessage
                });

                this.newMessage = ''
            }
        }    
    }
</script>
```

```
<template>
    <ul class="chat">
        <li class="left clearfix" v-for="message in messages">
            <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                <div class="header">
                    <strong class="primary-font">
                        {{ message.user.name }}
                    </strong>
                </div>
                <p>
                    {{ message.message }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['messages']
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Vue at its core is an in-browser JavaScript application. So the usual rules apply: open your debug window in your browser and check for errors. Put in console logging in any init code so you can see how far it does (not) get. Etc.